# What are the file:// protocol url encodings for these special characters(; $ % ^ #)

Tags: java, regex, urlencode, url-encoding, xmlworker

I have a case where image files contain special characters like `$ % ^ #`. In order to display these images on xmlworker generated pdfs, these need to be URL encoded.

We use `file://` protocol to place images on xmlworker generated pdfs, not the `https://` or `http://` protocol.

Kindly provide equivalent URL encoding for the following characters for `file://` protocol url.

1. #
2. $
3. %
4. &
5. +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try URLEncoder ;

```
String url = "file://=" + URLEncoder.encode("#aaaaa$bbbb%cccc&ddd+eeee", "UTF-8");
```

Output ;

> file://=%23aaaaa%24bbbb%25cccc%26ddd%2Beeee

And UrlDecoder;

```
String url = URLDecoder.decode("file://=%23aaaaa%24bbbb%25cccc%26ddd%2Beeee", "UTF-8");
```

Output

> file://=#aaaaa$bbbb%cccc&ddd+eeee

Comment: yes dear, i have done it. Its not serving the needful.The requirement of xmlworker framework is that it needs symbols encoded wrt the protocol. The encodings returned by the above method you wrote are of http.

Comment: @DevanshuKashyap: The percent encoding is defined by the [RFC 3986 URI Generic Syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) and is the same whether it's for http:// scheme or file:// scheme. Whether or not the encoding is interpreted, however, is dependant on the receiving program and its implementation. Generally it would have been a bug in the program if a program doesn't handle percent encoding appropriately.